# How to use this macro in my cpp program?

Tags: c++, macros

I have following macro with me. I am getting error while using this macro. If you observe it has no end bracket for  `schema::schema()` . This is my macro header file.

```
#ifdef _WINDOWS_SOURCE
#define ExportedByVX0TOOLS  __declspec(dllexport)  
#else
#define ExportedByVX0TOOLS
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
//
#if defined(_WINDOWS_SOURCE)
#include <errno.h>
#include <io.h>
#endif
#if defined(_IRIX_SOURCE) || defined(_SUNOS_SOURCE) || defined(_HPUX_SOURCE) || defined(_AIX)
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#endif

#define LoadSchemaDico(schema)\
        class ExportedByVX0TOOLS schema { public: schema();};\
        extern "C" ExportedByVX0TOOLS int fctCreate##schema();\
        int  fctCreate##schema(){ int ret=1 ; return ret; }\
        schema::schema(){
```

Comment: How are you using the macro as of now?

Comment: With some trepidation, I imagine!

Answer (score 1):

You can use it like so:

```
LoadSchemaDico(name)
//constructor code
}
```

Which will expand to:

```
class ExportedByVX0TOOLS name
{ 
   public: 
       name();
};
extern "C" ExportedByVX0TOOLS int fctCreatename();
int  fctCreatename()
{ 
   int ret=1 ; 
   return ret; 
}
name::name()
{
//constructor code
}
```

Comment: If i want to create the object for this expanded schema to c++ class, how can i do that??

Comment: @user1061293 you can just do "name obj;" or "name* obj = new name;", replacing name with the name of your class.

Comment: Thanks..But if i want to retrieve the name of the generated class at runtime, how can i do that..Usually we knows the name, because we give it. But i want to retrieve it run time like dynamic loading..

Comment: @user1061293 In this way, you can't. C++ doesn't support reflection. What might help you is the abstract factory design patter, might want to look into that.